# adicionar select field dinamicamente (projeto laravel)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, front-end

Eu to criando um formulário de um repositório e tenho vários campos como esse de modality. O que eu não sei fazer é criar uma função para que quando uma pessoa clicar no botão + ao lado do select, ele crie na tela outro campo select de modality exatamente igual ao primeiro (no caso, o da imagem) e que eu possa fazer meu loop pra alimentá-lo com os dados do banco.

Eu sou uma porta pra mexer com front end (creio que seja isso)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a função `.clone()` do *JQuery*, crie um select com as opções padrões sem id e oculto para servir como base, então quando clicar no add ele copia este select e exibe na tela, já para popular com dados do banco é a mesma função só coloque ela dentro de um loop para receber os dados.

JS

```
jQuery('select[name="default"]').hide();
jQuery('#addSelect').on('click', function() {
    var novoSelect = jQuery('select[name="default"]').clone();
    novoSelect.attr('name', 'select1')
    novoSelect.show();
    jQuery('body').append(novoSelect);
});
```

Html

```
<select name="default">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
<button id="addSelect">add</button>
```